# Use function to echo SQL results from external php file

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I'm getting weird results when trying to kind of make a "templating engine". Basically, I want to be able to use PHP variables that contain data from an SQL database.

What happens is that everything works properly with the PHP side, what does not is the page that needs to display this information (index.php).

I'm working on a way to get the website's name from the sql database, so I have something like that on my index:

```
 <?php 

 include ('php/data/sitename.php');

 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <title><?php echo $sitename; ?> - Home</title>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- HEADER: Navbar -->
        <?php $navbar; ?>
        <!-- MAIN: Index Page contents -->
        <?php $page_index ?>
        <!-- FOOTER: Footer -->
        <?php $footer; ?>
        <?php $sitename; ?>
    </div>
      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

This variable comes from a file (that has been included) called sitename.php, with the following code:

```
<?php
include ('../db.php');

$sql = "SELECT id, sitename FROM GeneralData";
$getname = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($getname->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $getname->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sitename = $row['sitename'];
        echo $sitename;
    }
}




?>
```

Yes, I used echo $sitename;, I know it wont echo the actual data, but I did it to test some things, and here are the results:

- Including the file sitename.php to index.php will do nothing, it would be like if it did not exist. However, if I write "echo "123";" on it, it will echo 123 on index. What does not work is what I need.
- If I go to sitename.php directly, it will simply output the correct SQL value I requested because I told it to echo (as I stated before). But, it wont work in index, it will simply not work.

Also, I'll leave my project structure here. It might help.
[image: contents]

What can I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use `eval()` to execute PHP code from a variable.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. You should use a real template library, rather than putting variables into the data.

Comment: How, exactly should I?

Comment: I think this is a scope issue. Because the var is declared in the other file, it isn't "visible' in your main file. Before your if statement, add global $sitename = ''; and see if that works.

Comment: you know $sitename; is not a global variable right?

Comment: Can you try to include the files with an absolute path instead of a relative one ? It could be that when you include the sitename.php into the index.php the db.php script might get lost, hence the issues you have...

Comment: Eek, I did not wanted to work with absolute paths...

Comment: How do I set it to be global? My IDE says it is wrong to just put global on it before the if statement.... It underlines red.

Comment: `<?php $sitename; ?>` you never echo'd that `<?php echo $sitename; ?>` - Edit: *"Yes, I used echo $sitename"* - where? Please don't post pseudo code.

Comment: This is not the case @Fred-ii-

Comment: I edited my comment, reload it. and how / where it's included.

Comment: also make sure your query didn't fail; check for errors using `mysqli_error($conn)` on the query and error reporting.

Comment: *"My IDE says it is wrong"* - never mind the IDE, test it on the server; I am starting to not grasp the question now and given the other comments and answer, it seems like there's something you may be leaving out here.

Comment: unless you update your question to contain the *exact* code and *exact* placement of your code and its included file(s), your question will remain unanswered. I'm looking at the comment you left under the answer below; we've all seen what you posted. What we haven't seen is what you *didn't* post. I'm really trying to help you here, but you're not helping by only posting what you think is relevant, and in bits scattered around.You have all the pieces to the puzzle here; I feel like you're only showing us a fraction.

Comment: ...if you're trying to include a file in the wrong spot, then that could be it. Again; use error reporting and check for errors on the query; there isn't anything else I can add to this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I edited the question. More detailed now. It might help!

Comment: I tested your code; got back success; taken from one of my db's with similar structure.

Comment: You got success? Can you please just show me the exact code you used? Thanks. @Fred-ii-

Comment: I sure 'nuff did. I'm just curious as to why you accepted the answer below; isn't this not yet solved? I ask this because of your asking me your questions above this one. As to which code I used; well... yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try set `GLOBAL` for sitename

```
GLOBAL $sitename;
```

or

```
GLOBALS['sitename'];
$sitename = ...
```

**EDIT**
try use

```
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/yourpath/yourfile.php";
   include_once($path);
```

Comment: you want when click in sitename , will direct to sitename.php right? You try add `href `

Comment: sorry man . checking your file path correcly . use ` $path = "../db.php";
  if(file_exists($path)){
     include $path;
  }else{
     die("{$path} ...");
  } `

Comment: Okay, I'll check this later. Also please sorry I mistreated you, I shouldnt have done this, you were just trying to help. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: it's my bad when not read correcly question . hope it help for you